# Where to put the UIAlert?

Tags: swift

Right now I got the Alert inside the ViewDidAppear,but because of this, the Alert shows up any time I reload the ViewController. I would rather like to implement the Alert this way, that the user only gets it the first time he enters he App.

Comment: Is the view controller displayed more than once or is it that you push/pop or present/dismiss other controllers which is why `viewDidAppear` is called more than once?

Comment: put it in viewDidLoad. it'll work as per your requirement.